# Error with css visibility property and javascript setTimeout method

Tags: javascript, css, visibility, settimeout

I have to make a `p` element disappear on click of a button while a `div` element slides over it. If the `p` element is already invisible and the `div` is already over it, then on click of the button the `p` should turn back visible but after 1 sec while the `div` slides off it.

The first portion works fine, in the second case instead doesn't work the setTimeout function used on the visibility property of `p`.

Here's the code:

```
function slide_wiki(){
    var wiki=document.getElementById('wiki_bar');
    var p_vita=document.getElementById('vita');
    var width=wiki.style.width;
    slide(wiki, 100);
    if(width!='0%'){
        setTimeout(function(){p_vita.style.visibility='visible'}, 1000);
        wiki.style.borderRight='1px solid #E0E0E0';
    }else{
        p_vita.style.visibility='hidden';
        setTimeout(function(){
            wiki.style.borderRight='0px solid white';
        }, 900);
    }
}
```

I created a jsFiddle as suggested, but for some reason the slide function doesn't work at all, still the css and javascript needed is there so it should help anyways.
http://jsfiddle.net/bigcola317/GRs3V/5/

Comment: have you got a jsfiddle? Have you tried the css `display` properties?

Comment: I would have tried it but it would ruin my design so I was hoping for a better solution..

Comment: if you provide a fiddle, we can work on getting the code right and then you can put it back into your design.

Comment: Created the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bigcola317/GRs3V/5/

Answer (score 1):

Since I couldn't see your code, I couldn't track the bug. So, instead I made a working solution using simple css transitions. See if it works for you: http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/V3yat/

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it. The problem was that after I would click the button if the "p" wasn't visible, slide() would execute a slide_close() function on the "div", setting new values for the style attribute on "p". I guessed the problem might have been that the style attribute could overwrite the settings made on the visibility property so I tried changing in the slide_close() function the setAttribute() method with:

```
p_vita.style.width="...";
p_vita.style.marginLeft="...";
```

and that made it work. It's not very clear but thanks anyways :)